# A part of textview in android to be clickable

Tags: android, string, textview, clickable, spannable

I have to display some text  in textview.
I just want the a part of the text to be clickable and the rest of the text to be normal.

Here is my code:

```
TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
String mText = "some text.Link to click.Some more text";
SpannableString sb = new SpannableString(mText);
sb.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        Intent in=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.twitter.com/"));
        startActivity(in);
    }
},  mText.indexOf("Link"),mText.indexOf("Link") + 13,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

mTextView.setText(sb);
mTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: I would just do an href and parse the whole string for the TextView as html. Text looks normal besides your link, that will appear blue.

Answer (score 3):

If you are putting the full url into the TextView you can use `android:autoLink="web"` to greatly simplify this process.

[See the TextView docs for more](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aautoLink)

Another option is the [Html object](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html). Specifically the `fromHtml()` method I think will allow you to achieve what you want. You should be able to do something like this:

```
mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("blah blah <a href=\"http://some.site.com\">some text to be linkified</a> blah blah"));
```

Comment: It might not be a url only. might be some text that I want to click and launch a third party app.

Comment: FoamyGuy has the right answer (but is not an answer,so I can't mark as correct).  I think the fromHtml() will be the most seamless.

Comment: @Booger you can't mark it as correct anyhow, it's not your question =p. I'll edit my answer though to add it.

Comment: @Booger/FoamGuy What if its not an url only..please check my earlier comment. It might be  a normal text also.

Comment: @androiddeveloper see the second part of my answer. I edited to add a method that should work for that case too. But also if you aren't using a url I suggest you edit your question since that is how you stated it.

Comment: @FoamGuy Edited my question. Your solution Works fine..But would be great if I would not have to create a separate textview because i get the text as a response from server and would have to display the entire thing on textview with only a part clickable

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `linkify` option: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html  - In this case,  you can just build your string dynamically, and make only the part of it you want clickable.

I had never heard of the `autoLink` attribute - cool.

Another option, which might be closer to your original question - you could create two different TextViews next to each other (if the spacing is odd, use `layout_marginRight="-8"`  - using a negative offset, which may require a bit of tweaking to get the spacing perfect).  Then you could apply the autoLink attribute to only the TextView you want to be clickable.